# Adjusting individual row height using cursor on JTable

Tags: java, swing

I have a JTable, on which I want to adjust the row height using mouse cursor(like in excel). Could you suggest how do i go about achieving this task.

Answer (score 3):

Found this code on the Sun/Oracle forums a long time ago...

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import javax.swing.event.MouseInputAdapter;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class TableRowResizer extends MouseInputAdapter
{ 
    public static Cursor resizeCursor = Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.N_RESIZE_CURSOR); 

    private int mouseYOffset, resizingRow; 
    private Cursor otherCursor = resizeCursor; 
    private JTable table; 

    public TableRowResizer(JTable table){ 
        this.table = table; 
        table.addMouseListener(this); 
        table.addMouseMotionListener(this); 
    } 

    private int getResizingRow(Point p){ 
        return getResizingRow(p, table.rowAtPoint(p)); 
    } 

    private int getResizingRow(Point p, int row){ 
        if(row == -1){ 
            return -1; 
        } 
        int col = table.columnAtPoint(p); 
        if(col==-1) 
            return -1; 
        Rectangle r = table.getCellRect(row, col, true); 
        r.grow(0, -3); 
        if(r.contains(p)) 
            return -1; 

        int midPoint = r.y + r.height / 2; 
        int rowIndex = (p.y < midPoint) ? row - 1 : row; 

        return rowIndex; 
    } 

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){ 
        Point p = e.getPoint(); 

        resizingRow = getResizingRow(p); 
        mouseYOffset = p.y - table.getRowHeight(resizingRow); 
    } 

    private void swapCursor(){ 
        Cursor tmp = table.getCursor(); 
        table.setCursor(otherCursor); 
        otherCursor = tmp; 
    }

    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e){
        if((getResizingRow(e.getPoint())>=0)
           != (table.getCursor() == resizeCursor)){
            swapCursor();
        }
    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){
        int mouseY = e.getY();

        if(resizingRow >= 0){
            int newHeight = mouseY - mouseYOffset;
            if(newHeight > 0)
                table.setRowHeight(resizingRow, newHeight);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is an old answer but I can confirm it does work perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If JTable doesn't support it natively then you are out of luck since this task will be quite difficult to manage.

What you will actually need to do is to write one or two listeners:

- a `MouseMotionListener`, that is able to track dragging of the mouse
- a `MouseListener`, that is able to track all the other mouse actions

Starting from this you will have to understand when the user starts to drag the mouse over a row separation line and then use the correct method: `setRowHeight(int,int)` (for a specific row) or `setRowHeight(int)` (for all rows).

This won't be easy and it suggest you not to try to do it dynamic (the height is updated while the mouse is moving).